# TestNG Report generation

Tags: java, xslt, testing, selenium, testng

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
@XStreamAlias(value = "Profile")
public class ProfileDTO
{
 ProfileDTO(String name, String address, String street, String phon_number, String houseNumber) {

    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.street = street;
    this.phon_number = phon_number;
    this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
}



String name,address,street,phon_number,houseNumber;

//getters n setters
```

Now there is one test Class NewTest.from there i m making an XML & Doing some operation .
if operation is Success or failure i will be having another type of XML

```
public class NewTest {
ProfileDTO dto =null;
String reqXML =null;

@BeforeClass
public void x() {
    dto = new ProfileDTO("abc", "USA", "street", "mobile", "42");
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    xStream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
    reqXML = xStream.toXML(dto);
    System.out.println("in B4 CLass :::"+reqXML);
}


@Test
public void testing() {
    //Post xml :::to some url::
    //  nd we got some response like..
    //<Response>
    //<Status> available </Status>
    //</Response>


System.out.println("test:: "+reqXML);
}
```

}

My question is that xml which i m posting..can i have that send xml and response xml in TEST REPORT.if test is success or failure doesn`t matter.
  Please Help in this topic.

Comment: Please clean up your question. What is it you want to do? What reporting system are you using? Are you using a continuous integration system? Which "xml" are you talking about?

Comment: hi bob
actually this is just like a rest services.
from one level to second we can go by xml.
& second level will return use required contents in xml only to first level.

Comment: so in addition of testing i want to print xml structures in report also.
else we need to copy each test xml one by one.for reference.

so only for client sack..i need to show them xml also.
this is my requirement.